# Can't have access to the menu of desktop unless I click any icon at the launcher

Tags: menu, nautilus-elementary

I have recently installed Nautilus Elementary for which I've read about [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/install-nautilus-elementary-2322-in.html).
I think after this change the problem arised.
Now everytime I log in my account and before clicking any other icons at the launcher I   cannot see the menu "File Edit View Places Help" on the top bar.
Even if I click an of the indicators I still can't access that menu.

What is wrong? Something with the "focus" of the application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to click the Desktop to get the menu to show, and yet it has to do with focus.

Comment: Why it isn't focused on the Desktop since nothing else has been clicked? :S Indeed I have to click at the desktop, I might haven't noticed it. Thank you.